# innerHTML not working in if/else

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a small text-based game and I'm trying to incorporate some background music through Youtube-embeds. Probably not the best solution, but for my goal it works :)

I have a Javascript database built up with multiple data collections, built up like this:

```
{
        "question":"blabla.",
        "answers":[
            {"title":"Left","response":3},
            {"title":"Right","response":2}
            ],
        "youembed":"<iframe id='youtube' width='100' height='100' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIIOVtWGSj8?autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    },
```

I place the content from the database in my HTML with the following piece:

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = db[currentLocation].question;
```

However, I only want the `youembed` to actually be placed in the HTML, if the length of `db[currentLocation].youembed` is over 0.

So I wrote the following:

```
if (youembed > 0) {
    document.getElementById("youembed").innerHTML = db[currentLocation].youembed;        
}
```

Whenever I use the `document[..].youembed` outside of the if-statement, it works without a problem, however, I want it to work IN the if-statement, so it doesn't replace the current playing song, until `db[currentLocation].youembed` is > 0

What am I doing wrong? I have an `alert(youembed)` placed in the code, so I can see the length and it does show me that one youembed is 0, the other on page 2 is 145, but it doesn't run the `if`-statement in that case.

Here's the complete Javascript code:

```
var currentLocation = 0;

window.printCurrentLocation = function(){
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = db[currentLocation].question;
    var youembed =  db[currentLocation].youembed;
    alert(youembed.length);
    if (youembed > 0) {
        document.getElementById("youembed").innerHTML = db[currentLocation].youembed;        
    }
    else {

    }

    var answers = "";
    for(var i=0,l=db[currentLocation].answers.length;i<l;i++){
        answers += "<p><button onclick='setLocation("+db[currentLocation].answers[i].response+")'>"+db[currentLocation].answers[i].title+"</button></p>";
    }
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = answers;
}

window.setLocation = function(num) {
    currentLocation = num;
    window.printCurrentLocation();
}

window.printCurrentLocation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
if(youembed.length){
   ...
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I set up a variable `youembed`. Please see the added Javascript code! :)

Comment: Oh man, of course I should also check the length in the if-statement! :/ Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the length, this right here

```
if (youembed > 0) { ... }
```

should be

```
if (youembed.length > 0) { ... }
```

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/f7cedqrf/